# geoserver and geonetwork to automatically ingest new raster files from a directory

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork

I have a data processing system regularly creating new raster files.
I would like geoserver 2.8 to detect the newly added file and ingest it, and I need geonetwork 2.10 to create a new entry (showing metadata, webservices pointing to geoserver WMS, WCS, WFS for the new layer) each time.
I can of course create xml files describing the meta-information.

Is there something already ready to use in geoserver/geonetwork?
Or shall I develop some scripts (in this case, can you give me a general structure or point me to resources)?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything to automatically pick up new data. But it would be easy to add it using the RESTful interface and a script.

Comment: You mean like the example shown here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html? Would you have a link to a comprehensive description of RESTful interface for geoserver/geonetwork?

Comment: https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager might help